Can the concept of a centroid be generalized to different distance metrics/spaces for a finite set of points?
As the title says, can we take the concept of a centroid and apply it to spaces where distances aren't simply the Euclidean distance as long as we have a finite set of points? Probably transforming it into a numerical optimization problem.
One avenue I found could be useful is the Chebyshev Center, though a bit unsure.

Think about the definition of centroid in Euclidean space, which should be $\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{k}\vec{OA_k}$ for the points $A_1,\cdots, A_k$, even you have distance function in arbitrary metric space, the sum of elements may not be well-defined

@AngaeMT What restrictions could be applied to the distance function so that the sum makes sense?

At least in your metric space, addition should be well-defined, that is for $x,y\in X$, you need to define what is $x+y$. In Euclidean/ vector space, these are easy to see, but it may not true in other spaces.

That makes sense, this means that I can't really apply it in my case. I was thinking about a possible generalization of the k-means algorithm and avoiding the assumptions of DBSCAN, though it seems it is not generally possible. My distance would've been number of hops in a tree.
Thanks for the insight!
